# Matrix multiplication in python giving error, How can I overcome this?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print the following pattern:

```
3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3
```

My python code is:

```
def pattern(n):
    d = n + (n - 1)
    l = [[0 for row in range(d)] for col in range(d)]
    for a in range(0, n):
        for i in range(a, d):
            for j in range(a, d):
                l[a][i][j].append(n)
        d -= 1
        n -= 1


print(pattern(3))
```

But I am getting the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  print(pattern(3))
File "test.py", line 7, in pattern
  l[a][i][j].append(n)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you expecting `l[a][i][j]` to do?

Comment: Look at the dimensions of `l`

Comment: @Phydeaux I am appending n value to list l using the index values.

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka you aren't appending to `l`, you are trying to append to `l[a][i][j]`. But `l` is a list of lists of integers, so `l[a][i][j]` throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to start from your own code even if the answer is a bit late...

You code tries to build an array of 0, and then writes decreasing values in sub-array. Simply you wrongly copied it. It should be:

```
def pattern(n):
    d = n + (n - 1)
    l = [[0 for row in range(d)] for col in range(d)]
    for a in range(0, n):
        for i in range(a, d):
            for j in range(a, d):
                l[i][j]=n
        n -= 1
        d -= 1
    return l
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But here my question is why you are assigning n instead of append. I though " l " is a list here right.!

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka `l` is indeed a list, as is `l[i]`. But as `l` was built with 2 dimensions, `l[i][j]` is a scalar...

Comment: Sorry to asking you this. I dont know about the scalar in python. May be outside of python also. Will you please explain it to me ?

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka: a scalar is a raw number and not an array, list or vector

Answer (score 4):

Because it's somewhat hard to understand how your code is supposed to do what it should (sorry!), here's a pretty Pythonic way to generate a matrix like this as a generator function.

```py
def pattern(n):
    size = n * 2 - 1
    n_1 = n - 1
    for y in range(size):
        yield [max(abs(x - n_1), abs(y - n_1)) + 1 for x in range(size)]
```

The idea is that we look at the "distance" of the cell we're generating from `n - 1`, which must be the center point of the grid (which is `n * 2 - 1` items wide and tall).

As it's a generator function, you can get a list-of-lists out of it by calling e.g. `list(pattern(size))`.

Here's an example program –

```
for size in range(1, 6):
    print(size)
    for row in pattern(size):
        print(row)
```

– and its output:

```
1
[1]
2
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
3
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
4
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
5
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

---

EDIT: As requested in comments, here's a simplified version which is not a generator function and doesn't use list comprehensions:

```py
def pattern_simple(n):
    size = n * 2 - 1
    n_1 = n - 1
    rows = []
    for y in range(size):
        row = []
        for x in range(size):
            row.append(max(abs(x - n_1), abs(y - n_1)) + 1)
        rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX. Is there any simple way, I mean that list comprehension is confusing me.

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka Sure, I added a simplified version in an edit. :)

Comment: Thanks You very much @AKX